# PFImageView issue: Can't display images from Parse in table view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to display an image with a `PFImageView` in a `UITableViewCell`. In an another view controller i successfully done it (without tableview). If the `self.senderId` is not a nil i make a query for the image and load it into the cell, but the `SUCCESS` log doesn't appears in the console, therefore it's possible that i missed something from the query (in my other view i'm using the [self.profilePic loadInBackground] inside the block. (However the app is running and i get no errors, just simply nothing appears in the image view.) I would be very happy if somebody could help me to solve this problem, because i have no idea what's wrong with my implementation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.senderId == nil) {
        NSLog(@"No updates.");
    }
    else {
        PFQuery *queryImage = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPicture"];
        [queryImage whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self.senderId];
        [queryImage orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [queryImage getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR.");
            } else {
                PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
                self.senderPicture = file;

                NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
            }
        }];
    }

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(reloadTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self setupUIForInput];

}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    OutputTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellThree"];

    cell.textOutput.text = self.senderId;

    if (self.senderId == nil) {
        NSLog(@"No updates.");
    }
    else {
    cell.self.profilePic.file = self.senderPicture;
    [cell.self.profilePic loadInBackground];

    }
        return cell;
}

-(void)reloadTable{
    [tableViewThree reloadData];
}
```

I also tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.senderId == nil) {
        NSLog(@"No updates.");
    }
    else {
        PFQuery *queryImage = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPicture"];
        [queryImage whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self.senderId];
        [queryImage orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
        [queryImage getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"ERROR.");
            } else {
                self.file = [object objectForKey:@"imageFile"];


                NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
            }
        }];
    }

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(reloadTable) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self setupUIForInput];

}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    OutputTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellThree"];

    cell.textOutput.text = self.senderId;

    if (self.senderId == nil) {
        NSLog(@"No updates");
    }
    else {
    cell.self.profilePic.file = self.file;
    [cell.self.profilePic loadInBackground];

    }
        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem was that i used an NSString for the self.senderId `[queryImage whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self.senderId];` instead of a PFUser object `[queryImage whereKey:@"user" equalTo:currentuser];`.